# how do I get an input field in html to ensure the pattern contains a specific country code eg 1472 followed by 3 number and then 4 numbers

Tags: html, input, numbers

I have different sign up pages that load for different countries, and I need the telephone input to be for that specific country, such as on one page it needs to be the country code 1234 followed by any 3 numbers and then any 4 numbers.  so I need the pattern for the input in the html form.  I am dealing with it on the server side with PHP, but I want to handle it on the client side via the input restriction pattern, as to be more efficient.  Im sure its really simple but I cant seem to find a simple solution.  thanks for your help

i tried the pattern restriction, i casn get the any 4 number, space, any 3 number, space any 4 numbers.  but i could not get the: '1234' specific number, space, any 3 number, space, any 4 numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, the pattern attribute used in the input verifies that the input follows the E.164 standard.
 The pattern `^+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$` accepts only strings beginning with + followed by 6-14 numeric characters(optionally separated by spaces) and a numeric character at the end:

```
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$" placeholder="+391234567890" oninput="if(this.value.length==3) this.value= this.value + ' '; this.value=this.value.replace(/^(\+39[0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})$/,'$1 $2 $3')" value="+39 " minlength="14" maxlength="14" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly')">
```

The `oninput` attribute used to format the phone number as the user includes it, in this case to format it as `+39 (XXX) XXXX XXXX` (Italian prefix, my country for simplicity)
 In addition, the value attribute is set to +39 so that the user cannot delete the international prefix.